# Retrieving target IP address from PDU Packet using SNMP4J

Tags: java, net-snmp, snmp4j, pdu

I had problem in retrieving the target ip address from received pdu.
The "getPeerAddress()" gave me the sender's ip address. But what I want is the ip iddress or host name in the command/received pdu.

Eg "10.255.255.221" from

snmpset -v 1 -c M 10.255.**.221 1.3.6.1.4.1.161.3.6.37.2.6.1.1.4.2 i 3.

I tried the getAgentAdress for pduV1 but nothing display.

```
public synchronized void processPdu(CommandResponderEvent cmdRespEvent) {
System.out.println("Received PDU...");

String retrieveIP = cmdRespEvent.getPeerAddress().toString().split("/")[0];
System.out.println("Received PDU from " + retrieveIP  +"\n");

PDU pdu = cmdRespEvent.getPDU();
System.out.println(" PDU Type = " + PDU.getTypeString(pdu.getType()));
System.out.println("Trap Type = " + pdu.getType());
System.out.println("IP Address = " + ((PDUv1) pdu).getAgentAddress().toString());
String updateValue = pdu.get(0).getVariable().toString();
System.out.println("updateValue ="+updateValue);
}
```

EDITED : My machine have multiple IP Addresses

Comment: Maybe I'm saying something stupid but since you are managing the received PDU, the target address should be your local IP address

Comment: but my local IP Address have a range from 1 to 100 , but I don't know which one is it..

Comment: I didn't try but you might check out `cmdRespEvent.getTransportMapping().getListenAddress()`

Comment: I've tried this , it doesn't give me the correct result ..